# "filtered query does not support sort" when using Hibernate Search

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, hibernate-search

I'm trying to issue a query which includes sorting
from Hibernate Search `5.7.1.Final`
to ElasticSearch `2.4.2`.

When I'm using curl I get the results:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/com.example.app.model.review/_search?pretty' -d '
{
    "query": { "match" : { "authors.name" : "Puczel" } },
    "sort": { "title": { "order": "asc" } }
}'
```

But when I issue the query from code:

```
protected static Session session;

public static void prepareSession()
{
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure()
        .buildSessionFactory();
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
}

...

protected static void testJSONQueryWithSort()
{
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
    QueryDescriptor query = ElasticsearchQueries.fromJson(
        "{ 'query': { 'match' : { 'authors.name' : 'Puczel' } }, 'sort': { 'title': { 'order': 'asc' } } }");
    List<?> result = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Review.class).list();

    System.out.println("\n\nSearch results for 'author.name:Puczel':");
    for(Object object : result)
    {
        Review review = (Review) object;
        System.out.println(review.toString());
    }

}
```

I get an Exception:

```
"[filtered] query does not support [sort]"
```

I understand where it comes from, because the query
that Hibernate Search issues is different than my `curl` query
- specifying the type is realised differently:

```
{
    "query":
    {
        "filtered":
        {
            "query":
            {
                "match":{"authors.name":"Puczel"}
            },
            "sort":{"title":{"order":"asc"}},
            "filter":{"type":{"value":"com.example.app.model.Review"}}
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to change it.

I tried using the sort example from Hibernate documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.7/reference/en-US/html_single/#__a_id_elasticsearch_query_sorting_a_sorting

But the example is not full. I don't know:

- which imports to use (there are multiple matching),
- what are the types of the undeclared variables, like `s`,
- how to initalise the variable `luceneQuery`.

I will appreciate any remarks on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as mentioned in the javadoc of `org.hibernate.search.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchQueries.fromJson(String)`:

> Note that only the 'query' attribute is supported.

So you must use the Hibernate Search API to perform sorts.

---

> which imports to use (there are multiple matching),

Sort is the one from Lucene (`org.apache.lucene`), `List` is from `java.util`, and all the other imports should be from Hibernate Search (`org.hibernate.search`).

> what are the types of the undeclared variables, like s

`s` is a `FullTextSession` retrieved through `org.hibernate.search.Search.getFullTextSession(Session)`. It will also work with a `FullTextEntityManager` retrieved through `org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(EntityManager)`.

> how to initalise the variable luceneQuery

You'll have to use the query builder (`qb`):

```
Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword().onField("authors.name").matching("Puczel").createQuery();
```

If you intend to use the Hibernate Search API, and you're not comfortable with it yet, I'd recommend reading the general documentation first (not just the Elasticsearch part, which only mentions Elasticsearch specifics): https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.7/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query

Comment: Thank you very much (again!). I got a bit confused about it, I thought that I cannot use `LuceneQuery` with ElasticSearch, but then I was trying to do it anyway, so it didn't have much sense without reading the whole chapter, what I did now. I fixed my code using your answer and now I understand the subject better. Thanks!